# ng2 i18n: use NOT english as a default language in templates

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I'm developing app for russian speaking people. English locale is 'backup'. 
So i'd like to see russian words in my templates to make it easier to understand.
It works fine, but injected `LOCALE_ID` is always 'en-US' if I don't provide in in module setup. Or it's always 'ru' if I provide, disregarding to the `--configuration` flag

Is is possible to set default language to NOT english?

My `angular.json` looks like

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
             ...
            "i18nLocale": "ru",
          },
          "configurations": {
              "en": {
                  "i18nFile": "app/assets/i18n/messages.en.xlf",
                  "i18nFormat": "xlf",
                  "i18nLocale": "en",
                  "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
              }
         }
```

I serve app with
`ng serve my-app --configuration en` for english and with for russian
`ng serve my-app`